# UIButton not being pressed in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to have a UIButton in a UITableViewCell. For some reason it is not letting the user interact with the button, only with the UITableViewCell. I do not know if code will help, but here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Answer";
    AnswerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell button
    cell.answerButton.buttonColor = [UIColor belizeHoleColor];
    cell.answerButton.shadowColor = [UIColor wetAsphaltColor];
    cell.answerButton.shadowHeight = 3.0f;

    //Set the tag and selector for the specific button
    cell.answerButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.answerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitAnswer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    cell.answerButton.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
    [cell.answerButton setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.answerButton setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    cell.answerButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    cell.answerButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.58f, 1.0f);

    //Cell Animation
    cell.answerButton.alpha = 0.0;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
     cell.answerButton.frame = newFrame;
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9
                      delay: 0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     cell.answerButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                     CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
                     cell.answerButton.frame = newFrame;
                 }
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                 }];

    if (indexPath.row == self.correctAnswerIndex) {
        //Set up cell
        [cell configureFlatCellWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] selectedColor:[UIColor clearColor] roundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners];

        cell.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
        cell.separatorHeight = 2.0f;

        //Set it so that if the string is too long there is a line break
        cell.answerButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.answerButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        //Set the text alignment to center
        cell.answerButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        //Set the text of the correct answer cell
        [cell.answerButton setTitle:capitalName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        //Set up cell
        [cell configureFlatCellWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] selectedColor:[UIColor clearColor] roundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners];

        cell.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
        cell.separatorHeight = 2.0f;

        //Set it so that if the string is too long there is a line break
        cell.answerButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.answerButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        //Set the text alignment to center
        cell.answerButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        //Set the text of the incorrect answer cell
        if (self.threeIncorrectAnswers.count != 0) {
            //Generate a random number based on the indexes of the array
            int randomIndex = arc4random() % self.threeIncorrectAnswers.count;
            [cell.answerButton setTitle:[self.threeIncorrectAnswers objectAtIndex:randomIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            //Remove the incorrect answer
            [self.threeIncorrectAnswers removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
        }
    }

    //Entering Animation
    cell.answerAnimationView.duration = 0.5;
    cell.answerAnimationView.delay    = 0.0;
    cell.answerAnimationView.type     = CSAnimationTypeFadeInLeft;

    // Kick start the animation immediately
    [cell startCanvasAnimation];

    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.answerAnimationView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.answerButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

Any thoughts on the problem? I am setting up the UITableViewCell in the Main Storyboard.If you need a screenshot of the storyboard I would be happy to post one. Thank you!

Comment: try adding in "`if (cell.answerButton == nil) NSLog(@"why is answer button nil??");`" at the top of that method and see if the NSLog prints out.  I'm thinking your outlet might not be connected properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I just tried and the answerButton is not nil.

Comment: what is your button' superview?

Comment: It is the CSAnimationView that I am using with the open source animation library, Canvas.

Comment: what is your canvas superview?

Comment: It is the content view and then the cell and then the table view

Comment: is you canvas' userInteractionEnabled property equal YES?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64076/discussion-between-pokobros-and-purrrminator).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `UIControlEventTouchDown` to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it still does not work. :(

Comment: Is is possible for you to send across the source so that I can take a look?

Comment: @PoKoBros Both the capitalsButton and funFactsButton are working for me.

Comment: I am talking about the QuizViewController's buttons

Comment: Are you running the app on the simulator or a device because the buttons are not being pressed for me.

Comment: @PoKoBros Tried it on Simulator - Both in iOS 8.1 and iOS 7.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64091/discussion-between-pokobros-and-sreejith).